# codiad in subdir results in error 500

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

i've installed codiad in a subdir of a webserver (xyz.com/codiad). the root dir .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddCharset utf-8 .js
AddCharset utf-8 .php
AddCharset utf-8 .md
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.htm$ index.php
RewriteRule (.+)\.md$ index.php
RewriteRule (.+)\.txt$ index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

trying to do the inital setup of codiad results in an internal server error 500 of the process

```
.../codid/components/install/process.php
```

and i assume codiad needs its own .htaccess file ..

i have to say that i have no access to the apache config files, only FTP to the webspace

generally, how can i override the .htaccess file of any parent directory ?

Comment: You _assume_? Maybe you should _know_ before taking action? Do you have access to the http servers error log file to find out what the actual issue is? You will need that anyway, you cannot operate web services without access to those log files...

Comment: agree with you.. i was too polite. its not my server, and i have no access to the log files.

Comment: Then it might be the best solution if you implement a virtual host together with the owner, so that your stuff is isolated.

Comment: solved. got the error.log. said: SoftException in Application.cpp:249: file is writeable by group. changed file permissions to 644 and then it worked. I was on the wrong track at the beginning.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm